# Fast drawing using NSBezierPath drawing at least 4000 segments

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, image-processing, drawing

I'm trying to draw about 4000-10000 segments using NSBezierPath on every drawRect of an NSView (about a 300x300 pixel box).  This is very resource heavy and is taking a lot time to draw (relatively long).

Can someone suggest a substitute for this?  I've tried using a single NSBezierPath for 1000 segments at a time, but it's still too resource heavy.

I'm looking for any possible alternatives.  I'm sure OpenGL would be faster, but I don't know if I have to learn a new platform in order to do what I need.  I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: 300 x 300 = 90000 and 10000 segments have 20000 endpoints. Assuming each segment very short, say 4 pixels, that adds another 40000 used pixels. So, 50% or more of your drawing surface may be filled, which seems very cluttered. Are you sure about those figures? Am I wrong?

Comment: From your second paragraph I assume those 4000+ paths can be considered copies/instances of one shape, right? And do the segments' (or at least a sub set of them) appearances differ at all among each other? (orientation, size, visual look, etc) Further more: do they overlap? And if yes: does z-order matter?

Comment: The z-order does matter, but the segments are not copies of one shape.  They are little line segments (random 4-10 pixels long).  They differ in color and orientation and are scrolled through the view.  Basically, it's a graph scrolling from right to left having many segments (hence lots of redraws, with lots of segments.)

Comment: You are correct.  The canvas can be bigger / smaller but the segments are always around the same number.  300x300 is more or less the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not an answer, just test results**

I did a simple experiment with Mathematica. This experiment gives us an absolute upper bound for your time, since I used no optimization, no GPU, an interpreted language, etc. So I think much more than one order of magnitude is achievable.

Results:

Generating a 10.000 bezier curves list

```
b = Table[
    {Hue[RandomReal[]], 
     BezierCurve@RandomReal[{0, 300}, {4, 2}]}, {10000}];
```

is very quick, because mathematica does not evaluate nothing.

Now rendering:

```
h1 = AbsoluteTime[]; Print@Graphics[b]; h2 = AbsoluteTime[]; Print[h2 - h1];

Time spent 11.8 secs
```

Result:

[image]

PS: The intention is to set a timing baseline for our mindset.

Comment: *poke!*  Haha.  I did review your answer and I was really saddened by the results.  I'm still here.  As an update, I found out that the biggest resource hog was the creation of NSBezierPath object.  Also, calling the 'stroke' message drains major cycles.  

This problem was solved by 1) only instantiating a single instance of NSBezierPath, and 2) calling stroke message once only after all the moveTo / lineTo's have been placed.  This sped up the processing by a factor of infinity (give or take 1%).  It takes less than .003 seconds to draw 10k line segments, which is absolutely ok in my book.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  Also, I think the reason why Mathematica takes so long is because it's an interpreter language.  It really should not take that much time.  Or, it's drawing a single segment at a time  (extremely consuming) instead of drawing the finished image once.

Comment: @David Glad to hear you solved you problem! As for the reason Mathematica took so long is clear: on purpose, I did it the most straightforward way, without optimizing absolutely nothing, just for being able to set a baseline time for your review, as you didn't mention any performance measurement.